# If I were or If I was

Tags: conditionals

Now I'm abroad, and my girlfriend is still in my country, her birthday was two days ago and I said " If I were there, I would do everything I could to pamper you"

Is that the correct usage of If I were or I should have said If I was?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that you said it on her birthday, or two days later?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think use of I were there is perfect

Comment: You should explain _why_ this is the case.

Comment: Asked question is completely hypothetical. For that hypothetical situation was keyword is inappropriate.

Comment: Please add the explanation IN the answer box. This is not an English quiz site, where giving the right answer is sufficient to move onto the next level.  ELU is a site that is supposed to *help* all learners. * Why* is "were" the correct response?

Answer (score 1):

According to the *Advanced Grammar in Use* (2nd edition) by Martin Hewings, Cambridge University Press:

- in **real conditionals** we usually use a **present tense verb** in the **if-clause** to talk about the future: "*If you **leave** now, you'll be able to catch the 5 o'clock train*";
- in **unreal conditionals** we can use **if ... were + to-infinitive** rather than **if + past simple** to talk about imaginary future situations, particularly to suggest it is unlikely that the situation in the **if-clause** will happen: "***If** the technology **were to become** available, we would be able ...*"

In *unreal* conditional sentences we can use **were** after any subject in the *if*-clause, including singular first and third person subjects (e.g. I/she/he/it). This use of **were** is sometimes called the *past subjunctive*, and is *generally preferred only in formal contexts*: "***If your mother were** here, I am sure she wouldn't let you eat all those chocolates*".
**Was** can be used instead of **were** with the same meaning. However, we prefer **were** rather than **was** when we give advice with **If I were you ...**.

Thus, it seems that both versions have the same meaning and are correct with the first one (with **were**) being a formal one.

Comment: I think the scenario is a little trickier. The birthday was two days ago; however the speaker would pamper his girlfriend today but they are living  in two different countries. Is he talking about the past event or the present?